# Chart JS always failed to load labels or legends when using ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

My Chart JS always failed to showing labels or legends when the data is from ajax response, The data is showing up but the legend always failed, I created my labels manually and assign it one by one but it's still doesn't work and ended up with error like **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fontSize' of undefined**, but when i change the chart type to pie or doughnut, my chart is working but still the legends or labels is not showing up.

here's my code :

```js
function getChartData() {
      $.ajax({
      dataType: 'JSON',
      method: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      url: '<?php base_url()?>/Rest_API/someurl',
      }).done(function(data){

          var timeseries = data['result']['timeseries'];

          var d1 = timeseries['0']['uniques']['all'];
          var d2 = timeseries['1']['uniques']['all'];
          var d3 = timeseries['2']['uniques']['all'];
          var d4 = timeseries['3']['uniques']['all'];
          var d5 = timeseries['4']['uniques']['all'];
          var d6 = timeseries['5']['uniques']['all'];
          var d7 = timeseries['6']['uniques']['all'];

          var l1 = timeseries['0']['since']
          var l2 = timeseries['1']['since']
          var l3 = timeseries['2']['since']
          var l4 = timeseries['3']['since']
          var l5 = timeseries['4']['since']
          var l6 = timeseries['5']['since']
          var l7 = timeseries['6']['since']

          var chartdata = [d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7];
          var chartlabels = [l1,l2,l3,l4,l5,l6,l7]
          
          //Create the chart.js data structure using 'labels' and 'data'
          var tempData = {
            labels : chartlabels,
            datasets : [{
              data : chartdata
            }]
          };
          
          var ctx = document.getElementById("chartPageRequest").getContext('2d');
          var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(tempData, {
          });
      });
    }
```

```html
<div class="GrafikchartPageRequest">
  <canvas id="chartPageRequest"></canvas>
</div>
```

and just for testing, I change my data and label manually inside the ajax done function like above :

```js
var tempData = {
            labels : ["1","2","3","4"],
            datasets : [{
              data : [4,5,6,7]
            }]
          };
          
          var ctx = document.getElementById("chartPageRequest").getContext('2d');
          var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(tempData, {
          });
```

but still thrown an error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fontSize' of undefined** that's mean the legends is failed to showing up. Thank you.

**UPDATE : AJAX RESPONSE**

[image: Ajax Response]

Comment: Please also post your html so we can make sure your id selector is correct, then we can debug the rest.

Comment: I haved post it, check it out after the js code @NathanielFlick

Comment: What does the response look like?

Comment: just thrown an error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fontSize' of undefined